# Measure irregular shape area with OpenCV

Tags: android, opencv, contour

I have no prior experience with OpenCV, so I've decided to ask here to get some feedback before spending hours trying to code the solution.

I want to make a small ad-hoc Android app to measure the surface area (in square feet or square meters) of irregular pieces of garment/fabric. Here's an example of how the pieces look like:

[image: Example of pieces to measure]

They range between 1 and 4 square meters.

A possible approach would be to place the items on a surface of known area (for example, a purple board of 2m x 2.5m):

[image: Solution example]

With OpenCV:

1. Identify the outer border of the purple board and get its area in pixels.
2. Identify the inner shape within the purple board and get its area in pixels.
3. Now we just calculate the ratio: the inner shape represents X % of the whole purple board. Since we know the SQFT of the purple board, we can get the shape's surface in SQFT as well.

Could this work? How accurate would it be?

Any suggestions/alternative approaches are welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Identify the outer border of the purple board and get its area in pixels: is possible, and easy to do with OpenCV.You have to somehow segment this area: by color, edges.
2. Identify the inner shape within the purple board and get its area in pixels: is possible, and easy to do with OpenCV. Just in first shape find specific color.
3. Now we just calculate the ratio: the inner shape represents X % of the whole purple board. Since we know the SQFT of the purple board, we can get the shape's surface in SQFT as well: is possible, and easy to do with OpenCV.

Accuracy depends on several factors:

1. Camera resolution
2. Camera position (the best position is the camera axis perpendicular to the plane with board and shape to measure)
3. Accuracy of shape segmentation